# Search query in android studio not workng properly

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc, android-asynctask

Okay so I made module for searching medicines and display items in a listview, I am using JDBC here. The main issue is when I place an underscore`_` in the searchview, It kind of makes a bug where the listview items duplicate themselves.

Based on my observation; this bug only occurs when the underscore is inserted simultaneously, but if pressed at slower interval, It doesn't duplicate items anyway.

---

**Here is what it looks without anything on the SearchView:**

[image]

---

**This is when underscores are placed at slower interval**

[image]

And even if underscores doesn't exist in the listview it still displays it, but when I add even more underscores, they started to disappear one by one starting from the bottom.

---

**And here's the main problem; when Underscores are placed simultaneously**

### [image]

Here are my code for the search in AsyncTask

```
private class searchUnfiltered extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

String z = "";
String fromSearchView = sv.getQuery().toString().trim();
boolean isSuccess = false;

String about;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    myArrayList2.clear();
    myArrayList.clear();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
        if (con == null) {
            z = "Please check your internet connection";
        } else {

            String querySearch = "select name from medicines where name like '%"+ fromSearchView +"%' order by name ASC";

            Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(querySearch);
            if(rs1 != null) {
                while (rs1.next()) {

                    myArrayList2.add(rs1.getString("name"));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        isSuccess = false;
        z = "Exceptions" + ex;
    }
    return z;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    if(!isSuccess && !z.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), z, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MedicineSearch.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArrayList2);
    lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
}
```

Whenever value is changed in search view the `searchUnfiltered` will be triggered, please tell me if what I'm doing is efficient or if you have any better suggestions, it would be very helpful.

Comment: I think problem is in search query. Try below query.

    String querySearch = "select DISTINCT name from medicines where name like '%"+ fromSearchView +"%' GROUP BY name ORDER BY name ASC";

Comment: Yes but it still returns anything even though there are no singlequotes existing in my list items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a race condition reason you are clearing the data onPreExecute then doInBackground is working typing 5 _ at a fast pace will clear 5 times before you get any results back.

as a Solution move:

```
myArrayList2.clear();// if this didn't work try myArrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

from onPreExecute to doInBackground.

Comment: did you try myArrayList2.clear() or myArrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: By pressing the button 3 times you cleared the array 3 times before task started while clearing inside doInBackground you will clear each time doInBackground is executed and they execute one by one. I am just assuming from experience.

Comment: You mean creating an instance of the `arraylist`? yes. So that means all actions should be inside the `doInBackground()` then?

Comment: onPreExecute can be as graying the field out or starting a progress bar(UI Work), doInBackground most computation or Network call(No UI work here), onPostExecute is more UI work. but this can vary with the objective in mind.